# Apache Storm - ClassNotFoundException on storm-starter

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm, classnotfoundexception

I’m trying to get the [storm-starter](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) to work. I tried the mailing list, and that does not seem to be gaining traction. When I run the following:

```
$ mvn compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

I get an [error](https://gist.github.com/sethgrid/c64eb01deec37f5b95d1):

```
Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.testing.TestWordSpout
```

I’m not a java developer, so I’m not sure exactly how imports are supposed to work. I do see `storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/testing/TestWordSpout.java`.

When I find any jar files, I see:

```
./target/original-storm-starter-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./target/storm-starter-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

When I inspect those jar files, `TestWordSpout` is not there. I am running my commands from `./examples/storm-starter` as per the documentation linked above.

To the best of my knowledge, I've followed the tutorial exactly. OSX El Capitan 10.11.2, Java 1.8.0, Storm 0.9.5., Maven 3.3.3. Any help would be great; I’d enjoy being able to get started :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a Storm Topology via maven is not the way to go. You should use `bin/storm jar myJarFile.jar` on command line to submit a topology to a cluster (which does also work for local mode).

The files `./target/original-storm-starter-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `./target/storm-starter-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` are standard maven artifacts and cannot be used to submit a topology to a cluster.

You can use `maven-jar-plugin` (which I would recommend to get started -- you might need to use `maven-dependency-plugin, too),`maven-assembly-plugin`, or`maven-shade-plugin`to assembly a correct`jar` file for submission. There is a bunch of SO question about this so I will not include further details here. For an example you can have a look into my git repository at https://github.com/mjsax/aeolus/blob/master/monitoring/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks @Matthias. If I understand you, you are saying to explicitly call out the dependencies I need via a maven plugin in the pom.xml file in the storm-starter project. That would still be using maven; is there a direct way to create the jar file to be run via bin/storm? These storm guys are not making this easy for someone completely ignorant of java to use their tutorial. I'll try looking into using this pom.xml thing. I'll post any updates. Thanks again.

Comment: update: I tried updating the pom.xml to explicitly declare TestWordSpout as an include and that did not work. Removing that, I `mvn package` and `storm jar target/storm-starter-*.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology` and it appears to be working.

Comment: I am also one of "those Storm guys" ;) The tutorial does not contain an example as assembling a jar is not really related to Storm (if you use Hadoop, Spark, Flink etc you have to do the exact same thing). Using maven is actually quite convenient for assembling a jar and all the required dependencies. Of course, you can assembly it manually, too. (Via command line for example; or via an UI -- a `jar` is the same as a `zip` internally.) Or you use a different tool like ant, sbt, etc...

Comment: Makes sense; thanks. And thanks for maintaining Storm.